# MongoDB and disk space

Tags: mongodb, diskspace

We have a MongoDB cluster with 4 shards.
Our primary shard disk space has 700GB, and according to db.stats() that shard is using ~530GB.
When checking df -h, the disk usage is on 99% (9.5 GB free), i'm guessing this means that all the rest is data files pre-allocated by Mongo.
I've ran compact on couple of collections, and the disk space was reduced to 3.5GB(?)

We're going to run a process that will generate ~140GB of extra data (35GB per shard).
Should we have any concerned on running out of disk space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing a lot of deletions? Mongo shouldn't preallocate more than a couple of GBs.

Comment: how about the size of your database files in `/var/lib/mongodb`?

Comment: Our database files is 693 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compact` doesn't decrease disk usage at all, actually it could even lead to additional file perallocation. To reduce disk usage you could use `repairDatabase` command or start mongo with repair option. However, it would require additional free space on disk.

Described situation could be the case if you did a lot of document deletions or some operations that forced documents to move. In this case your database would be highly defragmented. `compact` command helps you to reduce defragmentation and you will have more space for new records, but again, it doesn't reclaim any space back to OS.

Best option for you is to try to get why you have such level of defragmentation.

Comment: Hey Andrei, thanks for your comment.
Indeed, we have a scenario which has lots of deletions once a month of ~100 milion documents.
We also try to run repairDatabase occasionally.
What bothers us is that the OS doesn't reclaim the disk space, it remains under MongoDB control.
Is there a way to make Mongo 'give up' empty data files? or maybe yet, set a maximum disk space size mongo can allocate to his needs? (for example, 650GB)

Comment: To reclaim unused space you could use either repairDatabase, repair option or resync from scratch, no other ways as far as I know. Setting maximum disk space doesn't make a lot of sense( and not possible do mongodb level), because mongodb really needs additional space for new records. The reason of new space allocation is that it has no more space for new records.

Comment: Thank you, one last question if you don't mind.
Is there any built in way to alert when running low on disk space, besides waiting for either getting errors from Mongo or having the service crash?
Currently I have to use a workaround of getting db.stats() info per shard, and comparing it to the results from df command.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use MMS( free tool from MongoDB) in conjunction with munin(http://mms.mongodb.com/help/tutorial/configure-monitoring/) on all instances. MMS allows you to configure alerts based on criterias you define, fx you cound have alerts when low disk space